# Property 'results' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I am trying to get the `results` field from a json response however I get the error `Property 'results' does not exist on type 'AppComponent`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

//in place where you wanted to use `HttpClient`
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';

  // Inject HttpClient into your component or service.
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {

    // Make the HTTP request:
    this.http.get('assets/api/list.json').subscribe(data => {

      // Read the result field from the JSON response.
      this.results = data['results'];

    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because Typescript compiler checks that `results` variable exists/initialized in a class, before using it in any method.

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  results: any[]; //define it here

  // Inject HttpClient into your component or service.
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {

    // Make the HTTP request:
    this.http.get('assets/api/list.json').subscribe(data => {

      // Read the result field from the JSON response.
      this.results = data['results'];

    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes ['results'] will log the same error. (maybe for newer angular/ts versions)

```
 this.http.get(url).subscribe((data:any) => {

  // Read the result field from the JSON response.
  //this.results = data.results;
  this.results = data['results'];
```